# Python request-responce methods not working in PyCharm

Tags: python, request, pycharm

Code is working fine in atom editor, I wanted to know how I can resolve this issue with PyCharm.

```py
import requests
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/')


print(response.url)

# print status code
print(response.status_code)`
```

```
#####################################
ERROR
####################################
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kgowa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\cs330\7767.py", line 5, in <module>
    response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/')
  File "C:\Users\kgowa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kgowa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kgowa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kgowa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kgowa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 412, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "C:\Users\kgowa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 315, in get_connection
    conn = self.poolmanager.connection_from_url(url)
  File "C:\Users\kgowa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 298, in connection_from_url
    return self.connection_from_host(
  File "C:\Users\kgowa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 245, in connection_from_host
    return self.connection_from_context(request_context)
  File "C:\Users\kgowa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 260, in connection_from_context
    return self.connection_from_pool_key(pool_key, request_context=request_context)
  File "C:\Users\kgowa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 281, in connection_from_pool_key
    pool = self._new_pool(scheme, host, port, request_context=request_context)
  File "C:\Users\kgowa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 213, in _new_pool
    return pool_cls(host, port, **request_context)
  File "C:\Users\kgowa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 906, in __init__
    HTTPConnectionPool.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\kgowa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 197, in __init__
    self.pool = self.QueueCls(maxsize)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Process finished with exit code 1
```